# React router history is string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get started with react router in the browser using hash history, I copied this code from the guide for version 3.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {  Router,  Route,  Link, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
        </ul>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const About = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <h3>About</h3>
  }
})

const Inbox = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Inbox</h2>
        {this.props.children || "Welcome to your Inbox"}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const Message = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <h3>Message {this.props.params.id}</h3>
  }
})

var history = hashHistory;

console.log(history);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history="{history}">
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
),
document.getElementById('app-root'));
```

When I open the document I get these errors

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `history` of type `string`
>   supplied to `Router`, expected `object`.

I logged `history` before that and it looks like an object

[image]

> Uncaught Error: You have provided a history object created with history v4.x or v2.x and earlier. This version of React Router is only
>   compatible with v3 history objects. Please change to history v3.x.

I have installed `react-router@3` along with `history@3`, I can confirm

+-- react-router@3.0.2 extraneous

I can't find `history` in the list but if I go to the directory I can see the `package.json`

```
"version": "3.3.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "" sign from history

```
<Router history={history}>
```

Comment: facepalmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm